# how to convert excel cell value to string type?setting cell to text type in excel is not working

Tags: java, excel, apache, selenium

I am trying to read a value from excel sheet and enter it on text field there by
[image]
 comparing the values from webelement.[image]

how to get this value from cell as string and not numeric?
below is given code for reading and wrting excel

```
public String getValueFromCell(int iRowNumber, int iColNumber)
   {
      XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(iRowNumber);
      Cell cell = row.getCell(iColNumber);

      return cell == null ? "" : cell.toString();
   }

   /**
    * returns no. of rows of excel sheet
    * 
    * @return
    */
   public int getRowCount()
   {
      return sheet.getLastRowNum();
   }

   /**
    * returns no. of columns of excel sheet
    * 
    * @param sheetName
    * @return
    */
   public int getColumnCount(String sheetName)
   {

      sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
      row = sheet.getRow(0);
      return row.getLastCellNum();
   }

   /**
    * return row number of a String value
    * 
    * @param value
    * @return
    */
   public int getRowNumber(String value)
   {
      XSSFSheet indexsheet = workbook.getSheet("Index");
      for(int i = 0; i <= indexsheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
      {
         row = indexsheet.getRow(i);
         if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue()))
         {
            return i + 1;
         }
      }
      return 0;
   }

   /**
    * sets data in a cell
    * 
    * @param path
    * @param sheetName
    * @param colName
    * @param rowNum
    * @param data
    * @return
    */
   public boolean setCellData(String path, String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum, String data)
   {
      try
      {
         if(rowNum <= 0)
            return false;

         int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
         int colNum = -1;
         if(index == -1)
            return false;


         sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);


         row = sheet.getRow(0);
         for(int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++)
         {
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
               colNum = i;
         }
         if(colNum == -1)
            return false;

         sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);
         row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
         if(row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum - 1);

         cell = row.getCell(colNum);
         if(cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);

         cell.setCellValue(data);

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: Apache Poi version is 3.15,Excel version 2013, Formatting of cells in excel sheet is not resolving the issue .

Comment: while typing the value in excel prefix with '

Comment: what exactly and where exactly ?? dint get what you mean?

Comment: lets say in Excel cell you have typed 1234 replace it with '1234. Just try this am also not sure,,,

Comment: It worked like charm . thanks !! but please explain this solution  as why its working ?? and also is their any other way to do this in code

Comment: I think adding ' before numbers in Excel is converting them into strings. In code after reading the number just convert then into string. something like-> String value = new String(READ FROM EXCEL);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, we can achieve this in two ways.

**Method 1:** Add apostrophe(') before the numeric values on Excel. For Example, if you have 1234 in excel, then replace with '1234. Adding apostrophe will convert numeric into String.

**Method 2:** Handle it via Java. For example, do something like this,

```
String value = new String("value read from Excel");
```

Note: I haven't tested method 2 but it will actually work.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I too faced lots of issue in this. Just write the below two lines of Code. It will work.

```
Cell cell= data.getRow(i).getCell(0);
String orderID1=cell.toString();
```